# Upper bound on Ramsey number.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, proof-explanation, ramsey-theory

Let $n=R(p,q)$ be the Ramsey number i.e. the smallest positive integer such that is the edges of a complete graph with $n$ vertices be $2$-colored using colours $R$ and $B$ then either there exists a $K_p$ of colour $R$ or a $K_q$ of colour $B$.Now we know that $R(p,2)=p$ and $R(2,q)=q$ for all $p,q\geq 2$.Our objective is to find an upper bound for $R(p,q)$ .For that our instructor made the following claim:

$R(p,q)\leq R(p-1,q)+R(p,q-1)$

He gave it as an exercise and using that he showed that $R(m,\ell)\leq {m+\ell-2 \choose m-1}$.I am unable to prove the claim given as an exercise.Can someone show me a way out?

**Addendum**

I found a similar question on stack exchange [An upper bound for a graph Ramsey number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70616/an-upper-bound-for-a-graph-ramsey-number). But it deals with Ramsey numbers $R(G,H)$ of two graphs $G$ and $H$ ,with which I am not so comfortable.Also I did not understand the argument given there because I am not very comfortable with graph theory.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [An upper bound for a graph Ramsey number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70616/an-upper-bound-for-a-graph-ramsey-number)

Comment: @Arthur I am unable to understand that,it is more complicated than my version I think.

Comment: Then have you tried the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey%27s_theorem#Proof)?

Comment: @Arthur Thanks,it actually helps.

Comment: @Arthur I understand up to the step $R(r,s-1)+R(r-1,s)=|M|+|N|+1$ but the next step that $|M|\geq R(r-1,s)$ or $|N|\geq R(r,s-1)$ is still not understood.

Comment: If $|M|< R(r-1, s)$ and $|N| < R(r, s-1)$, that means $|M|\leq R(r-1, s)-1$ and $|N| \leq R(r, s-1)-1$, giving us $$|M|+|N|\leq R(r-1, s)+R(r, s-1)-2$$contradicting $|M|+|N|+1= R(r-1, s)+R(r, s-1)$. So one of the inequalities I started with must be false.